# How to convert a curl command to an Axios call in react (GET/PUT/ POST)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, axios

I am running into an issue with converting a cURL command into a working Axios call in React. I have 3 things I need to be able to do (and the cURL commands DO work) which is GET, PUT and POST. I have only found one resource here on S.O. that helps a little, though I am still not able to complete the call. The kicker is that I run into a CORS policy issue if I just do a Fetch to the website. Is there a way around this or a way to have React use the cURL command?

The resource I used to convert this cURL command is:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/745

Then I tried to make sure my synatax was correct by using the Axios Documentation: 
https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig

I am able to do a Fetch, but because of the CORS issue, I have to use the Heroku "CORS ANYWHERE" link, but this creates an issue when trying to PUT and POST. This link is ('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/')+ the url of the DB.

CURL Commands (that work):
GET -

```
curl -X GET -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer
```

POST -

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Michelob Ultra","likes":"-5"}' https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer
```

PUT -

```
curl -X PUT -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"likes":"22"}' https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/1
```

Axios GET request I tried:

```
  axiosGetData = () => { //Not working
    axios({
      url: "https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/",
      method: get,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(`Axios Call completed: ${res}`)
      });
  }
```

Error from the Axios Call:

```
TypeError: config.method.toLowerCase is not a function
    at Axios.request (Axios.js:43)
    at wrap (bind.js:11)
    at App._this.axiosGetData (App.js:53)
    at App.js:46
```

Comment: What is `get` in this case? Did you mean `"get"`? That error message *clearly* suggests a string was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So probably the issue is with `method: get`. Here get is a variable.
In your case it's undefined.
So you might want to use it as a string.

For example:

```
axiosGetData = () => { //Not working
    axios({
      url: "https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/",
      method: 'get',
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(`Axios Call completed: ${res}`)
      });
  }
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now I am working with CORS errors. Any idea on how to get around this in the Axios call? I will not be able to access it from the backend.

Here are the errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/ with MIME type application/json. 

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution you‘ve found is correct - but I think you have to use `get` as a String not as a Variable, since it is `undefined` 
In order to avoid such errors in the future you could use a linter like [`standard`](https://standardjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
axios({
    //...
    method: 'get',
    //...
}).then(onFulfilment);
```

the `method` property should be a `string`